# Why can't a external declaration be used as a type?

Tags: js++

In respect to static typing on JS++, why cannot we use external declarations as types? For example:

```js
external Uint8Array;

class ByteArray
{
    Uint8Array[] composingArrays;
}
```

The JS++ compiler terminates erroring that `Uint8Array` cannot be used "here" and expects a type. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use *JavaScript types* as types in JS++.

The concept of the *[external type](https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language/Reference/Types/Primitive-Types/external)* (sometimes called the *Unified External Type*) in JS++ means that all JavaScript types are treated as **one type** during compilation. (The *one type* being the `external` type. At runtime, `external` *unwraps* and can be any JavaScript type at runtime.)

The JS++ type system is basically the external types (unified into one external type), internal types (all JS++ types, including primitive types, arrays, user-defined types via classes, and so on), and the conversions between them.

One correct way to write your code would be:

```java
external Uint8Array;

class ByteArray
{
    var composingArrays;

    ByteArray(int size) {
        this.composingArrays = new Uint8Array(size);
    }
}
```

Examples of statements that can declare something with the external type include:

- [external](https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language/Reference/Statements/external) - used for importing JavaScript libraries
- [var](https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language/Reference/Statements/var) - used for declaring variables with the external type
- [function](https://docs.onux.com/en-US/Developers/JavaScript-PP/Language/Reference/Statements/function) - used for declaring functions that return values with the external type

Since `Uint8Array` has type `external`, you need the types to match (or have a possible conversion between them). Since `var` creates a variable with type `external`, and an instantiated `Uint8Array` has type `external`, the types will match.

In a more advanced usage, you might look at which types have a conversion available from the static `external` type and the runtime `Uint8Array` type.

Comment: So `var` is just an `external` alias. I think an `auto` thing would be also helpful.

Comment: I wouldn't call it an alias, but this sounds like it would be a topic for a new, separate question.

Comment: Yea, I meant statement.